# How to search through array with Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

So I am trying to match email to email domains (ie bob@test to @test.com). Both the array of emails and email domains are in separate arrays. Right now I am trying the following:

```
@Domains.each do |domain|
    if @Emails.include?(/.*/ + domain) then 
        #do stuff
    end
end
```

That is obviously throwing errors and I cannot find another solution. Any ideas?

Comment: No need for `then` in ruby

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search through array with regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417733/how-to-search-through-array-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are trying to do with a regex. This is a minimum fix to make it run. It does not use a regex.

```
@Domains.each do |domain|
  if @Emails.any?{|email| email.end_with?(domain)} 
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: I was trying to get it to match *@domain. I will try you suggestion, but it doesn't start with the domain, it ends with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with a hash, [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) the `@emails` array for matching patterns and associate both:

```
@domains.each_with_object Hash.new do |domain, matches|
  matches[domain] = @emails.grep domain
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@domains = ["hotmail.com", "gmail.com"]
@emails = ["blah@hotmail.com", "you@yahoo.com", "me@gmail.com"]
@a = []

@domains.each {|d|
  @a << @emails.select{ |e| e=~ /#{d}/ }
}

@a.flatten! #=> ["blah@hotmail.com", "me@gmail.com"]
```

Now I can do stuff with `@a`